# Error installing blueimp-file-upload-expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to [install](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/uploading-files-with-dropzone-js-and-express-js/) `blueimp-file-upload-expressjs`  using the following command:

```
npm i --save blueimp-file-upload-expressjs
```

but I having the following error:

```
npm WARN package.json wa-exercise-6-2014-2015@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json wa-exercise-6-2014-2015@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package is no longer maintained. See its readme for upgrade details.

> lwip@0.0.6 install /Users/cell/Desktop/AtelierBeatsProject/AtelierBeats/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-expressjs/node_modules/lwip
> node-gyp rebuild

2015-11-29 15:25:47.811 xcodebuild[26274:1595302] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 7265231C-39B4-402C-89E1-16167C4CC990 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/ClangFormat.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2015-11-29 15:25:47.812 xcodebuild[26274:1595302] [MT] PluginLoading: Skipping plug-in at path '/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/D for Xcode.xcplugin' because it is not compatible with this version of Xcode.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/decoder/init.o
In file included from ../src/decoder/init.cpp:1:
In file included from ../src/decoder/decoder.h:13:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:120:25: error: redefinition of '_NanEnsureLocal'
NAN_INLINE v8::Local _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local val) {
                        ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:115:25: note: previous definition is here
NAN_INLINE v8::Local _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle val) {
                        ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:207:68: error: too many arguments to function call,
      expected at most 2, have 4
    return v8::Signature::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), receiver, argc, argv);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
/Users/cell/.node-gyp/4.2.1/include/node/v8.h:4675:3: note: 'New' declared here
  static Local New(
  ^
In file included from ../src/decoder/init.cpp:1:
In file included from ../src/decoder/decoder.h:13:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:289:3: error: redefinition of 'NanNew'
  NanNew >(
  ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:282:3: note: previous definition is here
  NanNew >(
  ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:307:36: error: redefinition of 'NanNew'
  NAN_INLINE v8::Local NanNew(
                                   ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:301:36: note: previous definition is here
  NAN_INLINE v8::Local NanNew(
                                   ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:319:36: error: redefinition of 'NanNew'
  NAN_INLINE v8::Local NanNew(
                                   ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:313:36: note: previous definition is here
  NAN_INLINE v8::Local NanNew(
                                   ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:531:12: error: no matching function for call to
      '_NanEnsureLocal'
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(v8::Undefined(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())));
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:517:43: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:120:25: note: candidate template ignored: substitution
      failure [with T = v8::Primitive]
NAN_INLINE v8::Local _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local val) {
                        ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:536:12: error: no matching function for call to
      '_NanEnsureLocal'
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(v8::Null(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())));
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:517:43: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:120:25: note: candidate template ignored: substitution
      failure [with T = v8::Primitive]
NAN_INLINE v8::Local _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local val) {
                        ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:541:12: error: no matching function for call to
      '_NanEnsureLocal'
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(v8::True(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())));
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:517:43: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:120:25: note: candidate template ignored: substitution
      failure [with T = v8::Boolean]
NAN_INLINE v8::Local _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local val) {
                        ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:546:12: error: no matching function for call to
      '_NanEnsureLocal'
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(v8::False(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent())));
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:517:43: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:120:25: note: candidate template ignored: substitution
      failure [with T = v8::Boolean]
NAN_INLINE v8::Local _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local val) {
                        ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:778:13: error: no member named 'smalloc' in namespace
      'node'
    , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
      ~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:789:12: error: no matching function for call to 'New'
    return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/cell/.node-gyp/4.2.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: candidate
      function not viable: no known conversion from 'uint32_t'
      (aka 'unsigned int') to 'enum encoding' for 3rd argument
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/cell/.node-gyp/4.2.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: candidate
      function not viable: 2nd argument ('const char *') would lose const
      qualifier
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/cell/.node-gyp/4.2.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:28:40: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal New(v8::Isolate* isolate, size_t length);
                                       ^
/Users/cell/.node-gyp/4.2.1/include/node/node_buffer.h:36:40: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 3 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
In file included from ../src/decoder/init.cpp:1:
In file included from ../src/decoder/decoder.h:13:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:793:12: error: no viable conversion from
      'v8::MaybeLocal' to 'v8::Local'
    return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/cell/.node-gyp/4.2.1/include/node/v8.h:210:7: note: candidate constructor
      (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from
      'v8::MaybeLocal' to 'const v8::Local &' for 1st
      argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/cell/.node-gyp/4.2.1/include/node/v8.h:210:7: note: candidate constructor
      (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from
      'v8::MaybeLocal' to 'v8::Local &&' for 1st
      argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/cell/.node-gyp/4.2.1/include/node/v8.h:214:13: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match 'Local' against 'MaybeLocal'
  V8_INLINE Local(Local that)
            ^
/Users/cell/.node-gyp/4.2.1/include/node/v8.h:326:13: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match 'S *' against 'v8::MaybeLocal'
  V8_INLINE Local(S* that)
            ^
In file included from ../src/decoder/init.cpp:1:
In file included from ../src/decoder/decoder.h:13:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:800:26: error: no member named 'Use' in namespace
      'node::Buffer'
    return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1897:12: error: no matching function for call to
      '_NanEnsureLocal'
    return NanEscapeScope(NanNew(handle)->Get(kCallbackIndex)
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:517:43: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:120:25: note: candidate template ignored: substitution
      failure [with T = v8::Function]
NAN_INLINE v8::Local _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local val) {
                        ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1912:12: error: no matching function for call to
      '_NanEnsureLocal'
    return NanEscapeScope(node::MakeCallback(
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:517:43: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:120:25: note: candidate template ignored: substitution
      failure [with T = v8::Value]
NAN_INLINE v8::Local _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local val) {
                        ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1985:12: error: no matching function for call to
      '_NanEnsureLocal'
    return NanEscapeScope(handle->Get(NanNew(key)).As());
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:517:43: note: expanded from macro 'NanEscapeScope'
# define NanEscapeScope(val) scope.Escape(_NanEnsureLocal(val))
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:120:25: note: candidate template ignored: substitution
      failure [with T = v8::Object]
NAN_INLINE v8::Local _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local val) {
                        ^
16 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/decoder/init.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/cell/Desktop/AtelierBeatsProject/AtelierBeats/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-expressjs/node_modules/lwip
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "--save" "blueimp-file-upload-expressjs"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! lwip@0.0.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the lwip@0.0.6 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the lwip package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls lwip
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/cell/Desktop/AtelierBeatsProject/AtelierBeats/npm-debug.log
```

It seems a compatibility problem...

Comment: I'm having the same problem. How did you solve it?

Comment: @Clémentine I think I didn't manage to solve it. At the end I decided to use `multer` and create manually a dropdown zone even if I could probably have combined dropzone anyway with multer...Moreover, I didn't have much time to solve it, so that's why I gave up after a while, but maybe you're able to solve it, and if you do, then don't forget to post your solution ;)

Comment: I am fetching same issue, I am using jquery-file-upload and try with multer but does not worked, thats why I am trying to install but I stuck with last 1 day any alternate solution, I have to use jquery-file-upload anyhow.

Comment: This is ridiculous, going to have to go back to Multer which is also a half-broken piece of turd.

Comment: @igneosaur, The problem is likely the dependency with lwip. Lwip was using an outdated version of `nan` which caused it to not compile on systems using NodeJS v6. They published an update recently but seeing how the module `blueimp-file-upload-expressjs` hasn't been updated in a year I'd say chances are slim it will be fixed on that module anytime soon.

Comment: Gave it up on the `blueimp-file-upload-expressjs` module and I agree that it's not likely to be fixed soon or ever. I just tried [jQuery File Uploader Middleware](https://github.com/aguidrevitch/jquery-file-upload-middleware) using Node 5 and without further problems multiple file Ajax file upload works very smoothly now! Though this project hasn't been developed for two years...

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue. Got success in installation with this:

```
npm install arvindr21/blueimp-file-upload-expressjs
```